# Spring Amqp.outboundGateway()

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following flow:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, QUEUE)
    .transform(Transformers.fromJson())
    .transform(someService::iterator)
    .enrichHeaders(c -> c.headerExpression("iterator", "payload"))
    .split()
        .wireTap(wf -> wf
            .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate).routingKey(ANOTHER_QUEUE)))
        .filter("!headers['iterator'].hasNext()")
        .channel("launchBatchJob.input")
    .get();
```

Actually, this is working but leads to race condition between the queue and the job that start with an empty queue.

I've tried to use an Amqp.outboundGateway() because I want to be sure to start my job only after all items were queued, but it returns null and throws exception.

Are there better ways to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a publish subscribe channel after the split with two `.subscribe` subflows; one with an outbound channel adapter and the other with whatever you want to do in addition - i.e. add your `doSomething` flow as a subflow to the second subscribe.

See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#sub-flows-support) for an example but you don't need an executor; the second subflow will run after the first.

**EDIT**

I prefer to use wire taps for ancillary stuff like logging rather than purposes like you have in your edit, but what you have is functionally equivalent to adding a pub/sub channel.

Rabbitmq is async by default so there's no guarantee the message will actually reach the queue before the consuming task runs. You can `setChannelTransacted(true)` on the RabbitTemplate and the call will block until the commit succeeds. While that's not generally recommended for a high-volume app; it might be appropriate here. Otherwise you'll have to get involved with publisher confirms, which come back asynchronously.

Comment: Gary, sorry, my example was incomplete. I've updated the question.

Comment: Rabbitmq is async by default so there's no guarantee the message will actually reach the queue. You can `setChannelTransacted(true)` on the `RabbitTemplate` and the call will block until the commit succeeds. While that's not generally recommended for a high-volume app; it might be appropriate here. Otherwise you'll have to get involved with publisher confirms, which come back asynchronously.

Comment: I managed to solve this problem in a different way. I created a new step that queue all items and then start my job (I'm reusing an existent job) in the next step.